# How to get VirtualBox guest's name from guest

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

In VirtualBox, is there a way to get a guest VM's own name from within that guest? The closest I found was `VBoxControl guestproperty enumerate` but that did not include any of aforementioned values. I'm running VirtualBox 5.1.20, Windows Server 2012 on the guest, and guest additions are installed.

Note I am able to get that information from the host by calling `VBoxManage list vms`.

It would also be adequate if I could set "some string property" from the host via `VBoxManage` that could be read by the guest via `VBoxControl`

Comment: Related question: Does VM know that it is ran by VirtualBox?

Comment: VirtualBox Guest Additions are installed, so I would say yes

Comment: but even better if I could do without guest additions!

Comment: don‘t know if its possible but i guess you may need this to be able to tell on which VM you are while having multiple open. My Solution to this was to do different Color Themes on the different VMs. Hope this helps you also if not it may help others perhaps

Comment: Ha! I've already done the wallpaper thing when juggling VMs. That's very much needed. But for this problem, I'm looking for a programmatic solution I can have logs that specify a VM.

Comment: You might have luck with `dmidecode` equivalent for `windows`: https://serverfault.com/questions/171524/virtualbox-get-guest-uuid-from-within-the-guest-computer

Comment: I tried `wmic` which I read was supposed to be the equivalent, but it didn't have any of that info

Comment: same with `systeminfo`

Comment: I checked DMI and nothing. It should have been in OEM-defined of the chassis information but its not. In theory VBoxService knows about the state of the VM but it doesn't necessarily have the name metadata in it. I guess it should.

Answer (score 4):

I have luck by setting the `guestproperty` in `VBoxManage` and `VBoxControl`.

On the host:

```
VBoxManage guestproperty set SampleVm GuestName SampleVm
```

Then on the guest:

```
VBoxControl --nologo guestproperty get GuestName
```

Downsides are that this requires VirtualBox Guest Additions (for VBoxControl) and an extra call from the host.

Comment: This is adequate for my problem which is why I posted it. But I'm not going to accept the answer since I imagine (hope) there is a better answer out there

Comment: What does `wmic csprodct get uuid` return on `guest`?

Comment: Nice. That does indeed return the UUID. But I don't see the name anywhere in there. That would enable me to make a UUID-to-name lookup table and share it with all the guests.

Comment: FWIW there's a typo in that: `wmic csproduct get uuid`

Comment: It might be a UUID of the virtual machine, look for it in `VBoxManage list vms` on the host.

Comment: Yes. It's definitely the UUID of the VM

Comment: Is it on the list?

Comment: The `VBoxManage list vms` is the UUID-to-name lookup table I referred to a few comments back. I would need a way to send that to the guest VMs to get me the name on the guest. Certainly doable

Comment: Yes, the UUID returned from `wmic` is the same as the UUID in `VBoxManage list vms`. That's how I knew `wmic` returned the correct UUID of the guest

Comment: Is this a final answer for your question then? If I were you I would rely solely on that. Name can be changed - for example you can rename your `Windows` machine to `Windows_old` some day and you would have to update the table on the guest.

Comment: is what the final answer? the answer these comments are posted against? Or the answer we walked through in the comments? The one in the comments is certainly *an* answer, but IMO it's difficult because it involves the transfer of the `VBoxManage list vms` lookup table from host to guest

Comment: also, if names changes, I want the guest VM to have that new name. not the old name

Comment: It's not necessary to transform a list virtual names to the guest as I just said, I really wouldn't do that. You will always have a valid `UUID`, that's enough.

Comment: enough for what? I appreciate your help but the question is to get the name, not the UUID.

Comment: The answer is that it's not possible in `virtual machine` without manual work.