# How can I pass information to a Virtualbox guest machine?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have a Virtualbox image which I will run on several different machines. The guest OS, when booting, would need to know on which machine it is running (e.g., by retrieving the public IP or the hostname of the host machine). Sadly, Virtualbox's networking doesn't expose this information.

Is there a simple way to pass information from the Virtualbox host to the Virtualbox guest system? (Here, I want to pass the host IP address or hostname.) I could imagine configuring a dedicated service, e.g., an HTTP server (either on the guest or on the host), but this seems overkill; or I could imagine workarounds like exposing a fake USB device, etc., but is there a more convenient way?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this, assuming the guest OS has Virtualbox guest additions, is to use "guest properties": see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/guestadd-guestprops.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/vboxmanage-guestproperty.html) in the Virtualbox manual, and [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1280198/how-to-get-virtualbox-guests-name-from-guest) for an example.